Why doesn't the choice of listening port number generally appear to be a concern?
When writing a server application which opens a listening port, the choice of port number doesn't usually show up as a concern, provided no other application is currently holding that same port number open in listening state.
For example - let's consider an example server, which has 3 applications running with listening ports

A webserver on port 8080
Another webserver on port 8081, chosen because 8080 was already in use
Postgres on port 5432

Let's say we want to deploy another server application.

We choose port 8888, essentially at random. There is no particular reason for this choice

The other applications are running. They have accepted a large number of connections across a large number of port numbers.
Perhaps postgres has active, accepted, connections using port numbers 10666, 12543 and 13333, and 8888. These are just random made up numbers.
Since postgres is using port 8888:

does this mean we will not be able to start our new application (it wants to open a listening socket on the same port number as Postgres, which has accepted a connection with this port number)
why isn't this generally speaking a concern? - I have certainly never seen this show up as a problem in a production or dev environment before
I have seen port conflicts when two applications try to open listening connections to the same port number. I have not seen an application fail to start because the same port number is currently in use by an already accepted port number



Perhaps postgres has active, accepted, connections using port numbers 10666, 12543 and 13333, and 8888.

It seems here that you're referring to the remote port for the associated connections.
A connected TCP socket is defined by a 4-tuple:

local IP address
local TCP port
remote IP address
remote TCP port

Given your example, the local TCP port would be 5432 in all cases.  If the remote IP for the port 8888 case is not on the current host, there's no problem.
It's also not a problem if the remote IP happens to also reside on the local machine.  This is because a listening socket on a given TCP port doesn't conflict with a connected socket.  If it was a problem, there would be no way to accept connections, as each accepted connection has the same local IP and port as the listening connection.
As an example, suppose you use netcat to create a connection to the local SSH port (here 192.168.1.173 is the locally assigned IP) as follows:
nc -s 192.168.1.173 -p 1234 192.168.1.173 22

This creates two entries in the port list as follows:
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.173:1234      192.168.1.173:22        ESTABLISHED   # client
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.173:22        192.168.1.173:1234      ESTABLISHED   # server
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN     

Now if we create a listener on port 1234:
nc -l 192.168.1.173 1234

It succeeds.  Looking at the list of ports:
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.173:1234      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    # new server
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.173:1234      192.168.1.173:22        ESTABLISHED  # client
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.173:22        192.168.1.173:1234      ESTABLISHED  # server
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN     

We see that the newly started server doesn't conflict with the already open connection.

Cool, thanks for this - great answer! I think that means it is somewhat along the lines of what I suspected. Would it be correct to say the the OS considers ports in the LISTEN state to be independent to ports in the ESTABLISHED state?

@FreelanceConsultant Essentially, yes.


Why doesn't the choice of listening port number generally appear to be a concern?

It is a concern if you "randomly" pick a port that is used by another service on your machine.
The reason it is not a significant problem most of the time is that most people don't chose ports randomly.  In fact, they do it with fore-thought.
Most common services have assigned port numbers; i.e. numbers assigned by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA).  This Wikipedia page is a good summary of official assigned ports.  People will generally use the assigned ports; e.g. 25 for SSH, 80 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS, 5432 and 6432 for PostgreSQL.
When people do want to run two or more (say) web servers on the same IP address, they will pay attention to the ports that are currently or likely to be in use.  In some cases, there are conventional alternatives; e.g. 8000, 8008 and 8080 are conventional alternatives for port 80.  In other cases, one should pick a port that is unlikely to collide by consulting sources such as the Wikipedia page above.
However, if you do accidentally try to run two or more services listening on the same port, you will run into problems.  Only one service can listen on a given TCP port (or UDP port) at a time.  The other one will fail when it makes the listen syscall.
In short, it is not normally a problem because people don't normally chose port numbers randomly.


Since postgres is using port 8888:

does this mean we will not be able to start our new application (it wants to open a listening socket on the same port number as Postgres, which has accepted a connection with this port number)


Yes.


why isn't this generally speaking a concern? - I have certainly never seen this show up as a problem in a production or dev environment before.


Because ports are not generally chosen randomly.  Really.


I have seen port conflicts when two applications try to open listening connections to the same port number. I have not seen an application fail to start because the same port number is currently in use by an already accepted port number


If you have seen the former you have most likely seen the latter.  They are essentially the same thing.  (Unless I've misunderstood what you are saying ...)
FWIW, I sometimes encounter port conflicts myself, but the most common scenario is that I've tried to start a dev web server when I already had it running in a different shell.
